# How to open hyperlink cell automatically by google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I couldn't find how to open the hyperlink in same tab by button with google script in google sheet. Does anybody know how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Opening a link from a url in the sheet with a button on a dialog**

```
function gotoalinkwithadialogbutton() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  var href=rg.getValue();
  var html='<input type="button" value="Link" onClick="gotoLink();" />';
  html+='<script>function gotoLink(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(url){window.open(url);}).getLinkValue()}console.log("Here");</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Go To Link")
}

function getLinkValue() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();
}
```

- [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50154709/7215091)

The dialog could be a sidebar I believe.

Comment: I was just trying to find a way to do it with a button to answer the OPs question. Personally, I’d probably be happy to click on the link produced by the cell. But that wasn’t the question.

Comment: Ah yes. Missed the button part.